# SOLR EdgeNGramFilterFactory with exact search

Tags: search, solr, lucene, exact-match

I have implemented EdgeNgram into my `text` field, schema is

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- to do partial search -->
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="50" side="back"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

and `text` field is 
`<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>`

Every fields are copied to this `text` field.

Now, *problem* is before I added `EdgeNGramFilterFactoty` `q="This Organization"` was giving me `1` result but partial search as `q=thi` was not giving me any result,

But with added `EdgeNGramFilterFactoty` the `q=thi` gives me one result but `q="This Organization"` **(Exact search with NGram) stopped working - gives no result**. Is there a way to make *both* working?

Comment: By stopped working, do you mean, returns *no results*?

Comment: Yes now it returns no result.